# how to create custom api to get customer collection magento 2?

Tags: customer, catalog, rest-api, magento2.3.3, soap-api

I am beginner to create API in magento 2. Can anyone help me step by step process to create custom api to get customer collection.

Which is better **REST & SOAP**?

Also, How can I test this **custom API on postman**? Thanks in advance.